# 301 Redirect с домена на другой домен

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Настраиваю 301 редирект с одного домена на другой домен через .htaccess

Все работает. Только после перенаправления добавляется строка со старого сайта через символ ?

Мой код

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} /ru/equipment/other_equipment/Dix-AutoGramm [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site-new.ua/product/dix-autogrommets.html/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Получается результат

```
https://site-new.ua/product/dix-autogrommets.html?ru/equipment/other_equipment/Dix-AutoGramm
```

Comment: `RewriteRule (.*) https://site-new.ua/product/dix-autogrommets.html/$1 [R=301,L]` так пробовали?

Comment: Так вообще ошибка "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: А что у вас за первый домен?

Comment: @InDevX - первый домен com.ua - на .ua

Answer (score 0):

Помогло такое правило

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ru/equipment/other_equipment/Dix-AutoGramm$ https://site-new.ua/equipment/other_equipment/Dix-AutoGramm.html [R=301,L]
```